# Find value in Jade array

Tags: express, pug

I want to populate a html form using data passed through the variable 'object'. The form has some checkbox inputs. I thought I could perhaps check if a certain value exists in data.array, then add 'checked' to the box if it does. However, I have no idea if something like this is possible (without using mixins at least, as I can't get them to work in-line), or if there is an easier way to populate the checkboxes.

Checkbox item:

```
input.form-control(type="checkbox" value="item1" name="items")
```

Mixin:

```
mixin inArray(array, value)
    - for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            if array[i] === value
                    | checked
```

Attempted:

```
input.form-control(type="checkbox" value="item1" name="items" #[+inArray(object.items, 'item1')])
```

HTML result:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="item1" name="items" #[+inarray(object.items="" item1')]="" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Can you show us your code so far?

Comment: Sure, sorry, tried to implement a mixin to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method in conjunction with [boolean attribute](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#boolean-attributes) to check only checkboxes that contain a specific value:

```
input.form-control(type="checkbox" value="item1" checked=object.items.includes('item1'))
```

Comment: If my answer works for you, please consider [marking it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for future readers